# can i write one hbm file for two classes

Tags: nhibernate

i have two tables both are related with primary-foreign key ralation
and i have two corrosponding pojos

now can i write single property file(hbm) for both classes

if so can any one please give sample typical hbm file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we can write any number of classes in single hbm file